# Find all words in a string that contain <sub> tags using regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
CO<sub>2</sub> is one of the most abundant gases there is, while C<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> is very corrosive. Drink H<sub>2</sub> to stay hydrated.
```

I want to extract all the words from this string that contain the sub tags.

I have gotten as far as this for my regular expression, but I can't seem to figure out how to continue.

https://regexr.com/495sp

Comment: So your expected output should be "CO2", "C2SO", etc.?

Comment: No, the output should be including the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
/\w*<sub>\w*<\/sub>[^ \.]*/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MoQlPO/3)

Explanation:

- `\w*` - Matches any word characters before the first tag.
- `<sub>` - Matches the first opening tag.
- `\w*` - Matches the text between the first tags.
- `<\/sub>` - Matches the first closing tag.
- `[^ \.]*` - Matches any following characters that aren't spaces or full stops (in case the match occurs at the end of a sentence). Includes matching any further connected sub tags.
- `g flag` - Enables global search, causing all occurrences to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** to select all words that contain the `<sub>` tag

```
(\w+<sub>\w+<\/sub>)+
```

`\w+` Matches any word character

`<sub>` Matches the characters `<sub>` literally (case sensitive)

`<\/sub>` Matches the characters `</sub>` literally (case sensitive)

`+` Matches between one and unlimited times

Comment: But the desired output includes the characters before (and after) the tags.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I would like to select all words that contain the <sub> tag anywhere in them.

Comment: Have you tried it on the sample data from the question?  Does it pick out what's expected?  Methinks it might have problems with the chemically dubious `C<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>` which should be a single 'word'.  I think your regex treats that as two, doesn't it?  (Given the commentary, the `C` should be an `H` — hence the comment about 'chemically dubious'.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Updated

Comment: Much better.  I think a trailing `\w*` might be needed.  Think H2O with subscript notation.